# Скрипт не позволяет редактировать страницу

Tags: javascript, html5

попросили внести новую информацию на сайт, столкнулся с следующей проблемой - при редактировании html ничего не происходит, сайт находиться в изначальном состоянии. Стоит удалить пару скриптов проблема исчезает, но перестает работать один блок сайта. Помогите разобраться как поменять информацию на странице не убирая скрипты.

Вот один из этих скриптов

```js
(window.webpackJsonp = window.webpackJsonp || []).push([
      [2], {
        132: function(t, e, n) {
          "use strict";
          n(1), n(54);
          var r = n(17),
            o = n(7),
            c = n(8),
            f = window.__NUXT__;

          function l() {
            if (!this._hydrated) return this.$fetch()
          }

          function h() {
            if ((t = this).$vnode && t.$vnode.elm && t.$vnode.elm.dataset && t.$vnode.elm.dataset.fetchKey) {
              var t;
              this._hydrated = !0, this._fetchKey = +this.$vnode.elm.dataset.fetchKey;
              var data = f.fetch[this._fetchKey];
              if (data && data._error) this.$fetchState.error = data._error;
              else
                for (var e in data) o.default.set(this.$data, e, data[e])
            }
          }

          function d() {
            var t = this;
            return this._fetchPromise || (this._fetchPromise = m.call(this).then((function() {
              delete t._fetchPromise
            }))), this._fetchPromise
          }

          function m() {
            return v.apply(this, arguments)
          }

          function v() {
            return (v = Object(r.a)(regeneratorRuntime.mark((function t() {
              var e, n, r, o = this;
              return regeneratorRuntime.wrap((function(t) {
                for (;;) switch (t.prev = t.next) {
                  case 0:
                    return this.$nuxt.nbFetching++, this.$fetchState.pending = !0, this.$fetchState.error = null, this._hydrated = !1, e = null, n = Date.now(), t.prev = 6, t.next = 9, this.$options.fetch.call(this);
                  case 9:
                    t.next = 14;
                    break;
                  case 11:
                    t.prev = 11, t.t0 = t.catch(6), e = Object(c.o)(t.t0);
                  case 14:
                    if (!((r = this._fetchDelay - (Date.now() - n)) > 0)) {
                      t.next = 18;
                      break
                    }
                    return t.next = 18, new Promise((function(t) {
                      return setTimeout(t, r)
                    }));
                  case 18:
                    this.$fetchState.error = e, this.$fetchState.pending = !1, this.$fetchState.timestamp = Date.now(), this.$nextTick((function() {
                      return o.$nuxt.nbFetching--
                    }));
                  case 22:
                  case "end":
                    return t.stop()
                }
              }), t, this, [
                [6, 11]
              ])
            })))).apply(this, arguments)
          }
          e.a = {
            beforeCreate: function() {
              Object(c.l)(this) && (this._fetchDelay = "number" == typeof this.$options.fetchDelay ? this.$options.fetchDelay : 200, o.default.util.defineReactive(this, "$fetchState", {
                pending: !1,
                error: null,
                timestamp: Date.now()
              }), this.$fetch = d.bind(this), Object(c.a)(this, "created", h), Object(c.a)(this, "beforeMount", l))
            }
          }
        },
        134: function(t, e, n) {
          t.exports = n(135)
        },
        135: function(t, e, n) {
            "use strict";
            n.r(e),
              function(t) {
                n(59), n(2), n(52), n(20), n(21), n(42);
                var e = n(24),
                  r = (n(54), n(112), n(17)),
                  o = (n(84), n(85), n(3), n(1), n(4), n(14), n(115), n(145), n(152), n(154), n(7)),
                  c = n(128),
                  f = n(93),
                  l = n(8),
                  h = n(28),
                  d = n(132),
                  m = n(77);

                function v(t) {
                  if ("undefined" == typeof Symbol || null == t[Symbol.iterator]) {
                    if (Array.isArray(t) || (t = function(t, e) {
                        if (!t) return;
                        if ("string" == typeof t) return x(t, e);
                        var n = Object.prototype.toString.call(t).slice(8, -1);
                        "Object" === n && t.constructor && (n = t.constructor.name);
                        if ("Map" === n || "Set" === n) return Array.from(t);
                        if ("Arguments" === n || /^(?:Ui|I)nt(?:8|16|32)(?:Clamped)?Array$/.test(n)) return x(t, e)
                      }(t))) {
                      var i = 0,
                        e = function() {};
                      return {
                        s: e,
                        n: function() {
                          return i >= t.length ? {
                            done: !0
                          } : {
                            done: !1,
                            value: t[i++]
                          }
                        },
                        e: function(t) {
                          throw t
                        },
                        f: e
                      }
                    }
                    throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to iterate non-iterable instance.\nIn order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.")
                  }
                  var n, r, o = !0,
                    c = !1;
                  return {
                    s: function() {
                      n = t[Symbol.iterator]()
                    },
                    n: function() {
                      var t = n.next();
                      return o = t.done, t
                    },
                    e: function(t) {
                      c = !0, r = t
                    },
                    f: function() {
                      try {
                        o || null == n.return || n.return()
                      } finally {
                        if (c) throw r
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }

                function x(t, e) {
                  (null == e || e > t.length) && (e = t.length);
                  for (var i = 0, n = new Array(e); i < e; i++) n[i] = t[i];
                  return n
                }
                o.default.__nuxt__fetch__mixin__ || (o.default.mixin(d.a), o.default.__nuxt__fetch__mixin__ = !0), o.default.component(m.a.name, m.a), o.default.component("NLink", m.a), t.fetch || (t.fetch = c.a);
                var y, w, _ = [],
                  $ = window.__NUXT__ || {};
                Object.assign(o.default.config, {
                  silent: !0,
                  performance: !1
                });
                var O = o.default.config.errorHandler || console.error;

                function j(t, e, n) {
                  for (var r = function(component) {
                      var t = function(component, t) {
                        if (!component || !component.options || !component.options[t]) return {};
                        var option = component.options[t];
                        if ("function" == typeof option) {
                          for (var e = arguments.length, n = new Array(e > 2 ? e - 2 : 0), r = 2; r < e; r++) n[r - 2] = arguments[r];
                          return option.apply(void 0, n)
                        }
                        return option
                      }(component, "transition", e, n) || {};
                      return "string" == typeof t ? {
                        name: t
                      } : t
                    }, o = n ? Object(l.g)(n) : [], c = Math.max(t.length, o.length), f = [], h = function(i) {
                      var e = Object.assign({}, r(t[i])),
                        n = Object.assign({}, r(o[i]));
                      Object.keys(e).filter((function(t) {
                        return void0 !== e[t] && !t.toLowerCase().includes("leave")
                      })).forEach((function(t) {
                        n[t] = e[t]
                      })), f.push(n)
                    }, i = 0; i < c; i++) h(i);
                  return f
                }

                function C(t, e, n) {
                  return k.apply(this, arguments)
                }

                function k() {
                  return (k = Object(r.a)(regeneratorRuntime.mark((function t(e, n, r) {
                    var o, c, f, h, d = this;
                    return regeneratorRuntime.wrap((function(t) {
                      for (;;) switch (t.prev = t.next) {
                        case 0:
                          if (this._routeChanged = Boolean(y.nuxt.err) || n.name !== e.name, this._paramChanged = !this._routeChanged && n.path !== e.path, this._queryChanged = !this._paramChanged && n.fullPath !== e.fullPath, this._diffQuery = this._queryChanged ? Object(l.i)(e.query, n.query) : [], (this._routeChanged || this._paramChanged) && this.$loading.start && !this.$loading.manual && this.$loading.start(), t.prev = 5, !this._queryChanged) {
                            t.next = 12;
                            break
                          }
                          return t.next = 9, Object(l.q)(e, (function(t, e) {
                            return {
                              Component: t,
                              instance: e
                            }
                          }));
                        case 9:
                          o = t.sent, o.some((function(t) {
                            var r = t.Component,
                              o = t.instance,
                              c = r.options.watchQuery;
                            return !0 === c || (Array.isArray(c) ? c.some((function(t) {
                              return d._diffQuery[t]
                            })) : "function" == typeof c && c.apply(o, [e.query, n.query]))
                          })) && this.$loading.start && !this.$loading.manual && this.$loading.start();
                        case 12:
                          r(), t.next = 26;
                          break;
                        case 15:
                          if (t.prev = 15, t.t0 = t.catch(5), c = t.t0 || {}, f = c.statusCode || c.status || c.response && c.response.status || 500, h = c.message || "", !/^Loading( CSS)? chunk (\d)+ failed\./.test(h)) {
                            t.next = 23;
                            break
                          }
                          return window.location.reload(!0), t.abrupt("return");
                        case 23:
                          this.error({
                            statusCode: f,
                            message: h
                          }), this.$nuxt.$emit("routeChanged", e, n, c), r();
                        case 26:
                        case "end":
                          return t.stop()
                      }
                    }), t, this, [
                      [5, 15]
                    ])
                  })))).apply(this, arguments)
                }

                function S(t, e) {
                  return $.serverRendered && e && Object(l.b)(t, e), t._Ctor = t, t
                }

                function E(t) {
                  var path = Object(l.f)(t.options.base, t.options.mode);
                  return Object(l.d)(t.match(path), function() {
                    var t = Object(r.a)(regeneratorRuntime.mark((function t(e, n, r, o, c) {
                      var f;
                      return regeneratorRuntime.wrap((function(t) {
                        for (;;) switch (t.prev = t.next) {
                          case 0:
                            if ("function" != typeof e || e.options) {
                              t.next = 4;
                              break
                            }
                            return t.next = 3, e();
                          case 3:
                            e = t.sent;
                          case 4:
                            return f = S(Object(l.r)(e), $.data ? $.data[c] : null), r.components[o] = f, t.abrupt("return", f);
                          case 7:
                          case "end":
                            return t.stop()
                        }
                      }), t)
                    })));
                    return function(e, n, r, o, c) {
                      return t.apply(this, arguments)
                    }
                  }())
                }

                function R(t, e, n) {
                  var r = this,
                    o = [],
                    c = !1;
                  if (void 0 !== n && (o = [], (n = Object(l.r)(n)).options.middleware && (o = o.concat(n.options.middleware)), t.forEach((function(t) {
                      t.options.middleware && (o = o.concat(t.options.middleware))
                    }))), o = o.map((function(t) {
                      return "function" == typeof t ? t : ("function" != typeof f.a[t] && (c = !0, r.error({
                        statusCode: 500,
                        message: "Unknown middleware " + t
                      })), f.a[t])
                    })), !c) return Object(l.n)(o, e)
                }

                function P(t, e, n) {
                  return T.apply(this, arguments)
                }

                function T() {
                  return (T = Object(r.a)(regeneratorRuntime.mark((function t(e, n, r) {
                              var o, c, f, d, m, x, w, $, O, C, k, S, E, P, T, A = this;
                              return regeneratorRuntime.wrap((function(t) {
                                      for (;;) switch (t.prev = t.next) {
                                          case 0:
                                            if (!1 !== this._routeChanged || !1 !== this._paramChanged || !1 !== this._queryChanged) {
                                              t.next = 2;
                                              break
                                            }
                                            return t.abrupt("return", r());
                                          case 2:
                                            return e === n ? _ = [] : (o = [], _ = Object(l.g)(n, o).map((function(t, i) {
                                              return Object(l.c)(n.matched[o[i]].path)(n.params)
                                            }))), c = !1, f = function(path) {
                                              n.path === path.path && A.$loading.finish && A.$loading.finish(), n.path !== path.path && A.$loading.pause && A.$loading.pause(), c || (c = !0, r(path))
                                            }, t.next = 7, Object(l.s)(y, {
                                              route: e,
                                              from: n,
                                              next: f.bind(this)
                                            });
                                          case 7:
                                            if (this._dateLastError = y.nuxt.dateErr, this._hadError = Boolean(y.nuxt.err), d = [], (m = Object(l.g)(e, d)).length) {
                                              t.next = 26;
                                              break
                                            }
                                            return t.next = 14, R.call(this, m, y.context);
                                          case 14:
                                            if (!c) {
                                              t.next = 16;
                                              break
                                            }
                                            return t.abrupt("return");
                                          case 16:
                                            return x = (h.a.options || h.a).layout, t.next = 19, this.loadLayout("function" == typeof x ? x.call(h.a, y.context) : x);
                                          case 19:
                                            return w = t.sent, t.next = 22, R.call(this, m, y.context, w);
                                          case 22:
                                            if (!c) {
                                              t.next = 24;
                                              break
                                            }
                                            return t.abrupt("return");
                                          case 24:
                                            return y.context.error({
                                              statusCode: 404,
                                              message: "This page could not be found"
                                            }), t.abrupt("return", r());
                                          case 26:
                                            return m.forEach((function(t) {
                                              t._Ctor && t._Ctor.options && (t.options.asyncData = t._Ctor.options.asyncData, t.options.fetch = t._Ctor.options.fetch)
                                            })), this.setTransitions(j(m, e, n)), t.prev = 28, t.next = 31, R.call(this, m, y.context);
                                          case
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, инфомрацию о скриптах, которые вы удаляете и код самой страницы.

Comment: Добавил информацию

Comment: у вас сайт сделан на nuxt-е, вы редактируете компоненты из которых сделан сайт или что-то типа содержимого папки build?

Comment: сделайте сниппет кода, код нечитаем

Comment: @AndreyFreiz можно подумать в сниппете это читаемо станет

Comment: Редактирую файл index.html, разработчик не предоставил папку build

Comment: @teran согласен, лучше не стало

Comment: Просите у заказчиков или разработчика исходники (доступ к гиту к примеру)

Answer (score 2):

То, что вы видите в браузере, генерируется скриптами на JS. Редактировать html в такой ситуации без толку.

Тот JS-файл, который вы дали, не годится для редактирования - он сжат для выгрузки в интернет упаковщиком, в нем переменные в одну букву и т.п. Код обфусцирован, читать его, в общем, вредно для глаз.

Редактировать вам придется то, что подается на вход упаковщика. Не index.html.